# Removing duplicates in different files using Powershell

Tags: powershell, text, duplicates

Note: Still new to Powershell.

Lets say I have a several text files:

```
aAll.txt
aYellow.txt
aBlue.txt
aGreen.txt
```

`aAll.txt` contains 5 names:

```
Alex B.
John D. 
Peter L.
Teresa D.
George. I.
```

`aBlue.txt` contains 2 names:

```
Peter L.
Teresa D.
```

`aGreen.txt` contains 3 names:

```
Alex B.
John D.
Peter L.
```

`aYellow.txt` contains 2 names:

```
George I.
Teresa D.
```

Apologies for not explaining clearly enough earlier.
**Here is my pseudo code.** Never done this with text files before and only done with csv files in Python):

```
#list of my files
$listOfFiles = @(
"aAll.txt",
"aYellow.txt",
"aBlue.txt",
"aGreen.txt")
#this might be inefficient because what if I have 20 or 200 text files?

#loop through the list of files
foreach ($file in $listOfFiles) {

if ($file -contains "All") { #I don't want to alter the All.txt files
#skip that file
}
else {
$contents = Get-Content -Path "C:\User\Dupes\$file"

if ($contents is in another file) {
 #remove that line
 }
else {
 #go to next file
}

}}
```

(Note: No, there is no color order. As long as the duplicates are removed that is fine. Those names shouldn't be in any other file.

**This is my desired output when I go to check the text files:**

`aAll.txt` contains 5 names:

```
Alex B.
John D. 
Peter L.
Teresa D.
George. I.
```

`aBlue.txt` contains 2 names:

```
Peter L.
Teresa D.
```

`aGreen.txt` contains 2 names:

```
Alex B.
John D.
```

`aYellow.txt` contains 1 name:

```
George I.
```

So if this runs properly, duplicate names have been removed across the files. Total names in those 3 files altogether (excluding `aAll.txt`) is now 5.

Comment: SO is not a free script shop. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is there a preferred color order? In other words: Should Peter L. be removed from Blue or Green?

Comment: @noobCoder Your question is still way to vague. Did you actually read the comments? What have you tried so far? Show your code and explain what exactly you expect as the endresult.

Comment: Hi Olaf, thank you for the constructive feedback. I added some pseudocode and a desired output.

Comment: Actually you don't need the file `aAll.txt` at all. You could read the content of all desired files, combine every name with its according file name and group all this with `Group-Object` by the names from the content. Now you could delete all files and rewrite them using the names from the grouped array using only the first element of all groups ignoring additional group members if there are some.  (I voted to reopen your question)

Comment: Of course you could also write new output files to another folder leaving the original input files untouched. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Thank you, Olaf. Can you give me an example? So I looked on Microsoft's documentation for `Group-Object` and tried out this: `$path = "C\Users\Dupes\"` then `$hash = Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Group-Object -Property ".txt"` Then my output is `{aAll.txt, aBlue.txt, aGreen.txt, aYellow.txt...} ` where they're now grouped in a hash table. Am I somewhat on the right path?

Comment: Well, I could.  But that does not fit into a comment. We have to wait until your question is re-opened.

Comment: @DougMaurer would you agree to re-open the question since the questioneer added the explanation?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon would you agree to re-open the question since the questioneer added the explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already mentioned ... Actually you don't need the file `aAll.txt` at all. You could read the content of all desired files, combine every name with its according file name and group all this with `Group-Object` by the names from the content. Now you could delete all files and rewrite them using the names from the grouped array using only the first element of all groups ignoring additional group members if there are some.

Of course you could also write new output files to another folder leaving the original input files untouched.

```
$InputFolder = 'C:\_Sample\input\*'
$OutputFolder = 'C:\_Sample\output'

$FileList = 
Get-ChildItem -Path $InputFolder -Filter *.txt -File -Exclude aAll.txt 
$NamesNFilenamesList =
foreach ($File in $FileList) {
    Get-Content -Path $File.FullName |
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            File = $File.Name
            Name = $_
        }
    }
}
$NamesNFilenamesList |
Group-Object -Property Name |
ForEach-Object {
    $OutputFileName = 
    Join-Path -Path $OutputFolder -ChildPath $_.Group[0].File
    $_.Name | 
    Out-File -FilePath $OutputFileName -Append
}
```

Comment: Hi Olaf, I haven't checked SO in a while and didn't notice this was re-opened. This issue was resolved since then but you helped me a lot with this. So thank you again for the guidance ^-^ I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it helped. Just out of curiousity: Is the solution you've found anywhere near my code suggestion? If not I'd be curious to see how you solved it. 

Comment: I'd have to look back on the code. It has been a while, so I unfortunately don't recall at the moment. But I'll let you know :)